# GoogleDrive picker downloading login page content

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I am using Google Drive Picker in my project.The file is downloading but downloaded file contains the login page content.

```
    using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
 {if (fileName != null)
 {var saveFolder = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TempUploadDir"],Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
if (!Directory.Exists(saveFolder))
 {
 Logger.LogTrace("Attempting to create folder:" + saveFolder);
              Directory.CreateDirectory(saveFolder);
                            }
              path = Path.Combine(saveFolder, fileName);
              Logger.LogTrace("Saving uploaded document to local Path:" + path);
  if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
  {
   System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                            }
    client.DownloadFile(new Uri(urlAddress), path);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: You'll need to post sample code, show what you expect and what you receive, etc. There's no way we can help a problem of "It's not working" without seeing your implementation.

Comment: Hi Jake Can you please help me .I posted the code